# How to label the x axis with exact values

Tags: gnuplot

[image: current bar chart]

I have drawn the bar chart above using the following code:

```
set terminal jpeg medium
set output "bar.jpeg"  # shall be the name of the chart
set xlabel "full configuration time in msec"
set ylabel "Task rejection rate (%)"
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
#set autoscale

plot "data.data" using 1:2 with boxes
```

My file `data.data` looks like this:

```
2 9
5 24
7 46
10 66
15 100
```

I want the exact values 2,5,7,10,15 to appear along the x axis with the corresponding value along the y axis and to use a color other than red. What changes do I have to make to my code? I also need to remove that `"data.data" using 1:2` from the top right corner...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the key, use `unset key`.

The markers at the bottom of the graph are called `xtics`. If you want them to appear every 1, rather than every 2, then you could use `set xtics 1`. Depending on exactly what you wanted to do, you can customise the xtics even more. In gnuplot if you do `help xtics` there's plenty of information on that.

To change the colour of your boxes, you can use the `lc` (line colour) property. I have used a hexadecimal `#RRGGBB` format but you can also use names of colours like `green`, `blue`, etc. Look at `help linecolor` for more info on that.

Incorporating all of those changes into your script:

```
set xlabel "full configuration time in msec"
set ylabel "Task rejection rate (%)"
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid

unset key    
set xtics 1

plot "data.data" using 1:2 with boxes lc rgb '#52bb23'
```

[image: plot with changes made]

By the way, I used the `pngcairo` terminal rather than the `jpeg` one as I think it looks better. Try `set term` to see what terminals are available to you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @TomFenech's answer: If you want to show only the x-values specified in the data file, you can use the `xtic` function. Note, that in this case the defined x-format has no effect and the value is taken 'as-is':

```
set xlabel "Full configuration time in msec"
set ylabel "Task rejection rate (%)"
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
set xtics out nomirror

plot "data.data" using 1:2:xtic(1) with boxes notitle
```

[image]

Comment: A useful addition. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "the defined x-format"?

Comment: @TomFenech If you use e.g. `set format x '%.1f'` it doesn't have any effect on the x-values. You would need to use `xtic(sprintf('%.1f', $1))`.

Comment: OK, so the `set format x` line would be redundant. Thanks.